# How to read a multiple String values from text line and store them to a String variable(java)

Tags: java

I want to read line by line from a text file in java, one line consist of 4 fields but one field can contain multiple words, For Ex.:
I have this line: **Screen**    **Commercial**      **Problem with product**

How can I store this three fields of my line into 3 String variables in java?

```
var1 -> "Screen"
var2 -> "Commercial"
var3 -> "Problem with product"
```

Comment: How do you know which field has multiple words? Are they always at same position in text file. Also, post some code what you have tried so far

Comment: Where is what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

This splits the input. Use System.in instead of inputStream if reading from standard input:

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
String line;
while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
    String[] split = line.split(" ", 3);
    String var1 = split[0]; String var2 = split[1]; String var3 = split[2];
    // do whatever is needed...
}
```

Comment: Zbynek Vyskovsky - kvr000, what means this split: line.split(" ", 3);

Comment: It splits the string with passed argument as a separator, it can be regexp so you can use for example " +" to have unlimited number of spaces. The second argument limits the number of fields so whatever comes after second space will be single field.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, you'll want to use some specific character to indicate the breaks between fields. For example, `Screen|Commercial|Problem with product`. Then you could write code that reads the entire line as input and then divides it into substrings. For example:

```
File yourFile = new File(/*file path goes here*/);
Scanner sc = new Scanner(yourFile);
String input;
String var1;
String var2;
String var3;
int breakIndex;

while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
    input = sc.nextLine();
    breakIndex = input.indexOf("|");
    var1 = input.substring(0, breakIndex);
    input = input.substring(breakIndex+1);
    breakIndex = input.indexOf("|");
    var2 = input.substring(0, breakIndex);
    var3 = input.substring(breakIndex+1);
    // do whatever it is you plan to do with those variables here
}
```